# MySQL Transaction Isolation

Tags: mysql

I'm seeing duplicate rows in my history table - however the transaction that updates it first does delete from ; and then re-inserts the data for each one.  The other queries are correct (and work most of the time just fine).

How is it that the select statement can see an inconsistent view of the data?

```
create my_history_table (
  `a` int(11),
  `b` int(11),
  `timestamp` datetime
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

We update this table as needed with this:

```
  set autocommit=0;
  set transaction isolation level read committed;
  start transaction;
    delete from my_history_table;
    <loop on cursor inserting results for each>
  commit;
```

In another stored procedure we read these results back to the client:

```
select * from my_history_table join anotherTable using (a);
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was that delete from ;  was timing out on getting a lock but as of MySQL 5.0.31, that does not automatically roll back the transaction.  So it was doing the inserts without doing the delete and commiting that mess.